# Split date index to yearly index and monthly columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
data_date   value
2016-01-01  1
2016-01-02  2
2017-02-05  3
2017-02-07  4
2017-03-09  5
```

I need to convert it to a table with years as the index and months as the columns. (aggregate using sum)

The final output should look like this

```
      Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | ........... Dec |
2016  3   | xx  | xx  | xx  | ............    |
2017  xx  | 7   | 5   | xx  | ............    |
```

Here it what I did:

To make it easy to copy:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame([
 {'data_date': '2016-01-01', 'value': 1},
 {'data_date': '2016-01-02', 'value': 2},
 {'data_date': '2017-02-05', 'value': 3},
 {'data_date': '2017-02-07', 'value': 4},
 {'data_date': '2017-03-09', 'value': 5}])
```

I used TimeGrouper to first aggregate it to monthly like so:

```
df['data_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data_date'])
df.set_index('data_date', inplace=True)
grp_df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='M')]).sum()
```

So now I have data aggregated to each row as a month/Yr.
I'm stuck as to how to make months the columns and year the row.

Can you help me with that please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pivot_table:

```
(df.assign(year=df.data_date.dt.year, month=df.data_date.dt.strftime('%b'))
   .pivot_table(index='year', columns='month', values='value', aggfunc='sum')
   .reindex(['Jan','Feb','Mar','Dec'], axis=1)   # change this to correct month names
)
```

Or with `pd.crosstab`:

```
pd.crosstab(
    index=df.data_date.dt.year,
    columns=df.data_date.dt.strftime('%b'),
    values=df['value'],
    aggfunc='sum'
).reindex(['Jan','Feb','Mar','Dec'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
month  Jan  Feb  Mar  Dec
year                     
2016   3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
2017   NaN  7.0  5.0  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df['data_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data_date'])
df['year'] = df['data_date'].dt.year
df['month'] = df['data_date'].dt.month_name().str[:3]
df = df.pivot_table(index='year', columns='month', values='value', aggfunc='sum')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Your method is correct but answer didn't match because pivot_table the default aggregation is `mean`, but i needed `sum`

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that part, edited now

Answer (score 0):

If you need all the months of the year, a solution with `resample` might be helpful. There's no point doing this if you do not need it :

```py
df['data_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data_date'])
grp = df.set_index('data_date')
grp = grp.resample('M').sum().reset_index()
grp = grp.assign(year = grp.data_date.dt.year, 
                 month = grp.data_date.dt.month_name().str[:3])
grp['month'] = grp['month'].astype(pd.CategoricalDtype(grp.month.unique(),
                                                       ordered=True))
grp.pivot('year', 'month', 'value')

month  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
year
2016   3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2017   0.0  7.0  5.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```